# Usage Array.push method

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, jsperf

Tell me please, what is the faster way to push a value into array?

I have written a simple test to compare `push` and `a[a.length]=` methods:

push.js:

```
self.onmessage = function (event) {
  var n = Number(event.data),
      i,
      pushAr = [],
      pushStart,
      pushDuration,
      ar = [],
      start,
      duration,
      message;

  // Push
  pushStart = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    pushAr.push(i);
  }
  pushDuration = new Date() - pushStart;

  // explicit
  start = new Date();
  for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    ar[ar.length] = i;
  }
  duration = new Date() - start;

  message = "N = " + n;
  message += "\nPush duration: " + pushDuration + "; ";
  message += "Length duration: " + duration;

  self.postMessage(message);
};
```

main.js:

```
var worker = new Worker("push.js"),
    i;

worker.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event.data);
};

for (i = 4; i < 8; i += 1) {
  worker.postMessage(Math.pow(10, i));
}
```

And I got following results:

Chrome:

```
N = 10000
Push duration: 0; Length duration: 0
N = 100000
Push duration: 3; Length duration: 5
N = 1000000
Push duration: 56; Length duration: 90
N = 10000000
Push duration: 807; Length duration: 948
```

Safari:

```
N = 10000
Push duration: 1; Length duration: 4
N = 100000
Push duration: 2; Length duration: 2
N = 1000000
Push duration: 27; Length duration: 41
N = 10000000
Push duration: 283; Length duration: 461
```

FireFox:

```
N = 10000
Push duration: 1; Length duration: 0
N = 100000
Push duration: 2; Length duration: 2
N = 1000000
Push duration: 11; Length duration: 20
N = 10000000
Push duration: 279; Length duration: 412
```

Seems like `Array.push` is faster, but why some libs use `array length` instead? And what bonuses of such method? Why Chrome is so slow? Maybe some faster methods exist?

Comment: Differences in performance are too implementation dependent and aren't big enough to produce significant gains. Don't [optimize prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization); write the clearest code, then profile, then optimize.

Comment: The fastest method is to keep track of the index, (array[i]=value) instead of mesuring it each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are exactly the same, push is faster because the same algorithm (getting array length) works inside the script engine and not in the script. ar[ar.length] may be used if you need the result of that expression to be the new value, like in chained assigment `somevar = ar[ar.length] = "some new value"`

I found some other possible use - compatibility with older versions of javascript engine. In Microsoft documentation for JScript version 5.0 there's no mention of push method in Array object. And I actually found my own code from back then (around 2000) that actually uses `images[images.length] = s` code. So, maybe arrays didn't always have the push method.

P.S. Yes, MSDN cocumentation for push method says **version 5.5** is required and that wasn't even in windows 2000.

Comment: Agree, but the returned value is not important. If we go to `push` implementation, we can see, that algorithm do much more than pushing value into an array, there are also some checks for argument types and so on.. How is it faster? Native optimizations?

Comment: Yes, arrays are very micro-optimized by the vendors; they are good arguments in "fastest engine" discussions. Which version you use is more a question of believe :-) http://jsperf.com/index-vs-push/2

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries (e.g. jQuery) use `ar[ar.length]` because they don't use *real* arrays, but ArrayObjects, which don't have the `.push` method because they are Objects and not Arrays. Another trick that is used to solve that problem and that you might encounter often, is

```
Array.prototype.push.call(arrObj,'newValue');
```

The other reason for using `ar[ar.length]` is mentioned by Panda-34: chained assignments..!

Comment: But then they'd have to use `ar[ar.length++]`, don't they?

Comment: Yes, somewhere they should increase the .length of the ArrayObject, although not necessarily in the assignment itself.